# How to merge the string to another string

Tags: python

I would like to merge the name depending on what item it received.

For example, i have another function that return each list like below:

item:

```
["name"]
None
["name"]
None
["name"]
["king"]
None
None
["king"]
["king"]
```

These are returned to the function "def learn()" one by one.

```
def learn():
    #item goes in here one by one

    if item is None:
        return ["{]{}".format(xx,xx) for xx in item]
    else:
        return["{}{}".format(i,i) for i in item]
```

I wanted my output to be something like this: The None should take the same name as the second inserted list of string.

Output:

["name"]["name"]
["name"]["name"]

["king"]["king"]
["king"]["king"]

Comment: What is the original list being passed into `learn()`

Comment: How does `item` go into the function? Why do you want lists with one string each? Why do you want 4 strings with the "name" element when the input only has 3?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, but it looks like you just don't want the nones there. If that's the case on the very last line replace `return["{}{}".format(i,i) for i in item]` with `return ""`. If this isn't what you want, could you clearly write what the current output is, input is, and what the desired output is.